# When executing "gsutils cp" in python script I get Error message I do not understand

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I do the following call from within a Pyhton3 script on a master node of a GCP Dataproc cluster:

```
gsutil cp -r gs_folder local_folder
```

I get a message which I find a bit strange:

```
STDERR: b'ERROR: (gsutil) Failed to create the default configuration. Ensure your have the correct permissions o
n: [/home/.config/gcloud/configurations].\n  Could not create directory [/home/.config/gcloud/configurations]: P
ermission denied.\n\nPlease verify that you have permissions to write to the parent directory.\n'**********
GSUTIL COMMAND:
gsutil cp -r gs://my_source_paht /target_path
```

What I find odd is the location `/home/.config/gcloud/configurations` it mentions. Does this even make sense?

When I execute the same command from CLI of this machine as `sudo` then it works. So I am not sure: Is my current user not allowed to use gutil or 2) is it a permission problem regarding Google Storage?

Comment: This error means that the Linux user is not set up or you are using the root user. gsutil (gcloud) must be initialized while running under the identity meaning if you want to use this command while logged in as root, you must initialize (gcloud init) as the root user (sudo does not count).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the install has worked correctly. One would expect the install to setup configuration within ${HOME}/.config/gcloud. e.g. /home/mike/.config/cloud. But your install appears to be in /home itself. System wide configurations are normally located within /etc not /home.

Running `gsutil` gives an error because your user does not permission to write to /home (which is owned by root). Or permission to write to a subdirectory of /home. `gsutil` is trying to write to /home/.config/gcloud/configurations but does not have permission.